# Cannot log out after deploy to Heroku for Michael Hartl Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, logout

My app works perfectly on my development server, but after I deploy to Heroku, I cannot logout.

When I click on the log out button, it should redirect me to my root, which it does in development.

However, after I deploy on Heroku, it tries to direct me to "/logout" and fails. I do not get logged out. Please help.

I am new to this, so I am not sure what you need to see.

Comment: did u try  "run heroku run rake db:migrate" before deploying the app on heroku server?

Comment: `heroku logs --tail`

You should look at what errors pop up.

Comment: I looked back and "run heroku rake db:migrate did not happen. I misspelled migrate and did not realize it didn't migrate. Thank you, Nirupa!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to migrate production database with heroku, for that:

```
$heroku run rake db:migrate
```